# MAUI continue navigation after tapping on a Firebase notification and hitting the Login screen

Tags: firebase, authentication, maui

In creating our MAUI app, we have arrived to the following situation:

We have managed to finally send and receive notifications using Firebase - we get the little popup saying "You should approve or reject the following request...." and then, on tapping on it, the code should redirect the user to the request he is supposed to act upon. If the app is already running, it takes the user to that request (we use Shell.Current.GotoAsync()). Great.

However, if the app is NOT running, on clicking on the notification the user is taken onto the Login screen, he logins, and then.... nothing. The navigation should continue to the request item in question. How could we implement this ? Probably we should write code to handle Intents ? Or maybe we should simply create a file and save it somewhere on the device, and upon successful login the code should check whether it has that text file named, say, "ContinueNavigation.txt" and execute what's required and then immediately delete that file ?

Comment: You are not showing any code for handling the meta data you get from firebase and use it for deep link navigation. "(we use Shell.Current.GotoAsync())." is not enough to help you.

Comment: Please do not add signatures to posts. The profile card for each user is regarded as enough of a signature for Stack Overflow.